# Synchronizing different messages

Tags: c, stm32, can-bus

I think it's a general software paradigm problem, so it's not related that much to embedded software.

I have 3 Messages that I get at different time slices, the three messages are
Odo, velocity, gps. each one has timeslice 20ms, 1sec, and 1sec.

My problem is how would I sync and get a complete message only when the three are already fetched.

My current approach is to have three circural queues, and put three boolean variables and check if they are all in sync, but that doesn't work if for example odo which has timeslice 20ms, is pulled over and over without the other messages.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
void HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback(CAN_HandleTypeDef *hcan)
{

  HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage(&hcan1, CAN_RX_FIFO0, &RxMessage, RxData);
  static bool t1 = 0, t2=0, t3 =0;

  if (RxMessage.StdId == 0x098)
  {
    insertCirQueue(&q_velocity, 0x098);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12);
    t1=1;
  }
  else if (RxMessage.StdId == 0x309)
  {
    /* Rx message Error */
    insertCirQueue(&q_Odo, 0x309);
    t2=1;
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13);
  }
  else if (RxMessage.StdId == 0x3EB)
  {
    /* Rx message Error */
    insertCirQueue(&q_Gps, 0x3EB);
    t3=1;
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_14);
  }

  if (t1 && t2 && t3)
  {
    t2 = t3 = t1 = 0;
    isSynced = true;
  }
}
```

**and in the main loop**

```
 if (isSynced)
      {
        isSynced = false;

        int vel[8] = {0}, gps[8] = {0}, odo[8] = {0};
        int counter = 0;
        while (!isEmpty(&q_velocity))
        {
          if (deleteCirQueue(&q_velocity, &vel[counter++]) == -1)
              break;
        }

        counter = 0;
        while (!isEmpty(&q_Gps))
        {
          if(deleteCirQueue(&q_Gps, &gps[counter++]) == -1)
              break;
        }

        counter = 0;
        while (!isEmpty(&q_Odo))
        {

          if(deleteCirQueue(&q_Odo, &odo[counter++]) == -1)
             break;
        }
```

Comment: When you say timeslices, do you mean single data points at that time, or do you mean blocks of points?

Comment: @yhyrcanus single datapoint at that time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a bit-field, and set a bit per received message type.

```
typedef enum
{
  RECEIVED_NONE = 0x00,
  RECEIVED_ODO  = 0x01,
  RECEIVED_VELO = 0x02,
  RECEIVED_GPS  = 0x04,
  RECEIVED_ALL  = RECEIVED_ODO | RECEIVED_VELO | RECEIVED_GPS,
} can_received_t;



can_received_t can_received = RECEIVED_NONE;

if(/* received odo */)
{
  can_received |= RECEIVED_ODO;
}

...

if(can_received == RECEIVED_ALL)
{
  can_received = RECEIVED_NONE;
  ...
}
```

Storing queues seem fishy though. The normal procedure for CAN, being a real-time bus, is that you only keep the latest valid package and discard the rest. Particularly when dealing with sensors and control functions.

Comment: I'm interested also to retrieve the data that is received , what type of storage should I use for that.. that's why I used a circular queue

Comment: @andreahmed You should only need to store the latest message, so for standard CAN that would be an array of 8 bytes per message type.

Comment: @andreahmed Just declare an array of 8 bytes per message type? `uint8_t foo [8];`. It could be wrapped in structures but apparently ST's "HAL" is returning raw arrays with the data payload.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the last value received every time. So you could receive a bunch of updates for the odometer, but only "latch" it in when the last of gps/velocity have been collected (pick one to sync to). If you're getting them from a system that periodically and predictably sends you messages, that's easy. You don't even need a queue, except for finalized values (if you want to see/use trending history).

If you care about being synchronized *and* accurate, you could interpolate your velocity. Do the same thing as above for the odometer, and stop saving it once the GPS is collected. Collect 2 values for velocity (before the GPS collection, and after). Interpolate the velocity (linearly) to generate the velocity value at the GPS collection time. Then report that out. This will generate a synchronized and accurate value every time the velocity is collected, delayed by the offset between your velocity/GPS collection timestamps.